# Using wildcards for xpath query in the hpple library for iOS

Tags: html, ios, xpath, html-parsing, hpple

I am using the hpple library to parse an html document. The document looks something like

```
<a class="title threadtitle_unread">Promo - 20 Apr 2014</a>
<a class="title">                   Promo - 19 Apr 2014</a>
<a class="title unread">            Promo - 18 Apr 2014</a>
<a class="title special">           Promo - 17 Apr 2014</a>
<a class="title threadtitle_unread">Promo - 16 Apr 2014</a>
```

I want to retrieve all these nodes using an xpath query. So, I try to do something like

```
TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSString *xpathQueryString = @"//a[@class='title']";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:xpathQueryString];
```

But this understandably returns me only one node which is

```
<a class="title">                   Promo - 19 Apr 2014</a>
```

Can I form an xpath search query with wildcards so it returns me all these nodes? I tried to form the search query as

```
NSString *xpathQueryString = @"//a[@class='title']";
```

but this did not help.

Can I achieve this using hpple? If not, what are my other options?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible way is using `starts-with()` function :

```
//a[starts-with(@class,'title')]
```

Comment: Great. This works just fine. Is there also a way to ignore case? Like if some nodes are like <a class="TITLE">, I would want the xpath query to return those too.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the `contains` function. e.g.

```
//a[@class[contains(., 'title')]]
```